# Group policy to auto-enable plug and play disk

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, diskmanagement

Good afternoon,

I have an additional disk which is attached to the VM, however every time the server is rebooted the disk shows up in device manager but is disabled "due to group policy" I can then click enable and the disk comes on line.

I am told there is a group policy key I can change to make this happen automatically - does anyone know what this is and how to set it?

Comment: 1. What OSes are the host and VM running? 2. Is the "server" the host or the VM?

Comment: server = VM =window-server-2012, its hosted on openstack

Comment: How does the VM think the disk is attached?

Comment: shows up in device manager as a Redhat VertIO SCSI disk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open an elevated command prompt, run `diskpart`. From there, run

```
san policy=OnlineAll
exit
```

Comment: Excellent that's got it :)